# Glider Slideshow Tabs Not Working With Two Slideshows - Prototype

Tags: javascript, slider, prototype

I have two glider slideshows on one page. Slider #1 (#slider) will display the tab that's active for Slider #2 (#slider2) instead of the active slide from Slider #1. I need the link to change its class to "active" for the correct slider.

Here's where it's happening:

```
this.current = $(element);

$$('#slider div.controls a.active').invoke('removeClassName', 'active');
$$('#slider2 div.controls a.active').invoke('removeClassName', 'active');
$$('#slider a[href="#'+this.current.id+'"]').invoke('addClassName', 'active');
```

Here's my HTML code:

```
<a href="#section1">1</a>
<a href="#section2">2</a>
<a href="#section3">3</a>
```

Example Fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/hVGRy

Comment: Are you sure $ is jQuery and not another library ? And there is no addClassName in jQuery.

Comment: It uses Prototype for the effects. I get this code from here http://code.google.com/p/missingmethod-projects/issues/detail?id=4#c12

Comment: Could you put your code in a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: I guess you `$` doesn't stand for jQuery, since jQuery returns `jQuery([])` when no elements found, but not `null`.

Comment: You are using prototype and jQuery on the same page?

Comment: I thought jquery used `.addClass()` not `.addClassName()` http://api.jquery.com/addClass/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using the `$` symbol in Wrong ways.

In Prototype, `$` and `$$` are so much different from each other:

- `$` equals `document.getElementById`, returns matched element, if not found, return `null`;
- `$$` equals `document.querySelectorAll`, returns array with matched elements, if not found, returns `[]`.

You code should look like this:

```
$$( '#slider div.controls a.active' ).invoke( 'removeClassName', 'active' );
$$( 'a[href=' + this.current.id + ']' )[0].addClassName( 'active' );
```

---

OK, the original one only work with one slide, here's a hack for multiple slides:

```
// glider.js
addObservers: function() {
  var controls = this.wrapper.getElementsBySelector('.controls a');
  controls.invoke('observe', 'click', this.events.click);
}

moveTo: function(element, container, options){
  this.current = typeof element === 'string' ? this.wrapper.getElementsBySelector( '#' + element )[0] : $( element )

  this.wrapper.getElementsBySelector( '.controls a.active' ).invoke( 'removeClassName', 'active' )
  this.wrapper.getElementsBySelector( 'a[href="#' + this.current.id + '"]' ).invoke( 'addClassName', 'active' )

  Position.prepare();
  var containerOffset = Position.cumulativeOffset( container ),
  elementOffset = Position.cumulativeOffset( this.current );

  this.scrolling  = new Effect.SmoothScroll(container, 
    {duration:options.duration, x:(elementOffset[0]-containerOffset[0]), y:(elementOffset[1]-containerOffset[1])});
  return false;
}
```

Tested on my machine.

Comment: This works with one slider. I need it to work with two sliders.

Comment: @Daniel post a sample code with two slides on jsfiddle or jsbin, and clarify your question.

Comment: @Daniel if you need "clicking on slide #1, slide #2 changes slide instead slide #1", I think you can just binding a click event on slide #1, if it's fired, trigger slide #2's click event.